# Is it computationally cheap to generate hashes that have a specific prefix?

Tags: hash

Let's say we want to generate a hashed value that starts with "abc". Is it computationally cheap to find out an input? Note that here we just want to find any input whose hashed value starts with "abc".

###### Background

I found the following vulnerability and its security fix.

- https://github.com/rack/rack/security/advisories/GHSA-hrqr-hxpp-chr3
- https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/7a4cf249ac8ab2a709bba03e4d16da0059eab4b8

It seems still vulnerable to the timing attack, if we can cheaply generate hashed values that have certain prefixes.

Comment: This was [SHA-1 leading zeros](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83227/18298), however, you can change it for any cryptographic hash function.

Answer (score 1):

For a cryptograhpically secure hash function, the only way to find an input that produces an output with a specific prefix is to try random inputs until you find one that works.

This means that for a prefix of N bits, on average you need to try 2<sup>N</sup> inputs. For the prefix "abc" which is 12 bits, you would need to try 2<sup>12</sup> = 4096 inputs on average. So for a small prefix this is relatively cheap, but as the prefix grows it gets exponentially more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it was not cheap. As the length of the prefix grows, it matches the hash value itself. Then we have to guess the input from the whole hash value which is costly.